# How to pass yyyy-mm String to yyyy-mm-dd datetime string to filter records from sqlite?

Tags: android, sqlite, datetime

Here i have Datetime string in yyyy-mm-dd format like

1. 2016-08-26
2. 2016-09-21
3. 2015-07-23
4. 2016-04-25

What i need is if pass 2016-08 in parameter i need to get record of 2016-08-26 like that i need to get how can i achieve this so far what i have tried is

```
  public List<CustomerModel>date(String year){
        String countQuery ="SELECT * FROM "+CustomerModel.CustomerTable + " where " +CustomerModel.Customer_CreatedAt +  " strftime('%Y-%m',"+CustomerModel.Customer_CreatedAt+")  = "+year  +"";
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
        List<CustomerModel>list=new ArrayList<>();
        if(cursor!=null && cursor.getCount()>0){
            if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
                do{
                    CustomerModel accountModel=new CustomerModel();
                    accountModel.setCreatedByName(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(CustomerModel.Customer_CreatedBy)));
                    //   accountModel.setCreatedat(cursor.getString(1));
                    list.add(accountModel);
                }while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }
        }


        if(cursor!=null){
            cursor.setNotificationUri(mcontext.getContentResolver(),DB_Timetracker );
        }
        return list;
    }
```

Am getting sqlite exception how to achieve this is it possible to do this Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try this query

```
select * from table_name WHERE created_date LIKE '2016-08%'
```

This will give you multiple records if you have more than one date for that particular year and month. Replace the date with your sting using string functions from the date field.

Comment: method not returning anything

Comment: @M.Yogeshwaran what's the type of time in your database

Comment: Magizhchi @PreetikaKaur

Comment: what is the datatype of your field?